# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) when sourcing files inside the R file

Tags: r, knitr, lyx

I have a problem of environment when I try to "knit HTML" or generate a pdf with LyX.
When I run directly the R code (or compile an HTML notebook with Rstudio), it's ok.
I have done the test with knitr@1.3.7 (dev version). I had not the problem with knit@1.2

On the sample given here after (test.Rhtml > test.R > init.R > kCommon.R), The returned error is :

```
Period: From

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : objet 'kStartDate' introuvable

to
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : objet 'kEndDate' introuvable
```

**test.R**

```
## @knitr INIT
source("./init.R")
print(kStartDate)
print(kEndDate)
```

test.R sources **init.R**

```
if (!require(xtable)){
  install.packages("xtable")
  library(xtable)
}
source("./kCommon.R")
```

init.R sources **kCommon.R**

```
# Period
kStartDate   <- as.Date("2013-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d")
kEndDate     <- as.Date("2013-06-30", format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

**test.Rhtml**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>

<!--begin.rcode set-options, echo=FALSE
output <- "html"
read_chunk('test.R')
opts_chunk$set(fig.width=7, fig.height=4.5, fig.align='center', tidy=FALSE, comment=NA) 
end.rcode-->
<!--begin.rcode INIT, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE
end.rcode-->
<p>
Period: From <!--rinline as.character(kStartDate) --> to <!--rinline as.character(kEndDate) -->
</p>


<hr/>
<p>
This document has been generated with <!--rinline version$version.string -->
on <!--rinline version$platform -->.  <br/>
[<!--rinline date() -->]
</p>
<!--begin.rcode FIN, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE
end.rcode-->

</body>
</html>
```

**Session info**

```
> library(knitr);sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/C/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.3.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3   evaluate_0.4.6 

formatR_0.9    stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.1
```

**Results** (after removing the options)

```
output <- "html"
read_chunk("test.R")
opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 7, fig.height = 4.5, fig.align = "center", tidy = FALSE,
    comment = NA)
Period: From

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : objet 'kStartDate' introuvable

to
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : objet 'kEndDate' introuvable

This document has been generated with R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) on x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0. 
[Thu Aug 8 10:35:22 2013]

#EOF#
```

**Log**

```
> require(knitr); knit('test.Rhtml', encoding='UTF-8');
Le chargement a nécessité le package : knitr


processing file: test.Rhtml
  |.........                                                        |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...................                                              |  29%
label: set-options
  |............................                                     |  43%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.....................................                            |  57%
label: INIT
  |..............................................                   |  71%
   inline R code fragments

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : objet 'kStartDate' introuvable
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : objet 'kEndDate' introuvable
  |........................................................         |  86%
label: FIN
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: test.html

[1] "test.html"
>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with knitr v1.3.7; can you add the output of `library(knitr);sessionInfo()` to your post?

Comment: I added the session info in the post.

Comment: can you remove the chunk options `echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE` in `INIT`, compile test.Rhtml again, and paste the output of that chunk?

Comment: I have removed all the chunck options. I added the result and the log in the post.

Comment: The `INIT` chunk was not in the output, which means it was not read into the document. That is very weird. Can you put all these files in a zip file (or tar ball) and send to me by email? xie@yihui.name

Answer (score 1):

The example code you gave in `test.R` in the post was overly simplified, and the script you sent to me is actually this:

```
##-------
## @knitr INIT
##-------
source("./init.R")

print(kStartDate)
print(kEndDate)
```

That makes a difference, because of the [new syntax for external code chunks](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md) (search for `----` in the NEWS). If you just want to fold code chunks in RStudio, see this question [Code folding in external files with knitr and RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473990/code-folding-in-external-files-with-knitr-and-rstudio)

Answer (score 0):

one way to solve the issue is to clear knit cache pressing the button or setting this environment variable to FALSE, see it below:

```
{r setup, include=TRUE, cache = FALSE}
```

Cheers!